# installing valgrind ./configure fails to produce makefile

Tags: 14.04, kernel, valgrind

I'm trying to install valgrind and it looks as though `./configure` is failing with `configure: error: Valgrind works on kernels 2.4, 2.6`.

Does this mean that I have to install a new kernel?  The Linux VM I am using is required for a college course, so I am reluctant to fundamentally modify it.

Is there another way around this?

Here is the rest of the output:

```
adminuser @ ~/valgrind-3.6.1 --> ./configure
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... no
checking for mawk... mawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking whether to enable maintainer-specific portions of Makefiles... no
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking for style of include used by make... GNU
checking dependency style of gcc... gcc3
checking whether gcc and cc understand -c and -o together... yes
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
checking for g++... g++
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... yes
checking whether g++ accepts -g... yes
checking dependency style of g++... gcc3
checking for ranlib... ranlib
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /bin/sed
checking for ar... /usr/bin/ar
checking for perl... /usr/bin/perl
checking for gdb... /usr/bin/gdb
checking dependency style of gcc... gcc3
checking for diff -u... yes
checking for a supported version of gcc... ok (4.8.2)
checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking for a supported CPU... ok (x86_64)
checking for a 64-bit only build... no
checking for a 32-bit only build... no
checking for a supported OS... ok (linux-gnu)
checking for the kernel version... unsupported (3.13.0-39-generic)
configure: error: Valgrind works on kernels 2.4, 2.6
```

Comment: You can edit the configure script to skip that step, but there is probably a very good reason why it claims to only work on those kernels. (Read: Then it will probably fail further down the road).

Comment: Which kernel does your VM use atm? And why Valgrind 3.6.1? ( [Valgrind 3.10.1](http://valgrind.org/) is current).

Comment: 3.13.0-39-generic

Comment: oops, I was very stupidly following the version in the installation tutorial instead of entering the most recent version!  My bad, thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be fixed in Valgrind 3.7.0 and later. If you don't have any particular reason to use such an old version of Valgrind you should probably use the current version (3.10.1).

Comment: I have the same problem. It doesn't work on Ubuntu 16.04 . I cant install 3.11 because it doesn't support random_device.